# Issue with List.clear & Object sync method was called from an unsynchronized block of code

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I am having hard time to figure out problem with List.Clear() method. My application is crashing there in different times for example 30mins to 5hours. It happens pretty randomly.

Code below is started in background thread.
I have also some other threads working at the same time and some could use the loggedData1 & loggedData2 variables.

```
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (LoggingEnabled)
        {
            var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            #region - Reset logging variables
            loggedData2.Clear(); // List
            loggedData1.Clear(); // List
            #endregion

            // Lots of more code
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Crashing exception given is "Object synchronization method was called from an unsyncronized block of code"
}
```

How could I fix that, I am pretty new to Threads. Thanks for help.

Comment: `List<T>` is not thread-safe. Consider using a `ConcurrentBag<T>`

Comment: You didn't shown us where is the problem. Am pretty sure you have `Monitor.Exit` call or `lock` somewhere, post that code. Otherwise hard to help.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov `ConcurrentBag` doesn't have `Clear()`.

Comment: @svick Then any other concurrent collection with a clear. It was a suggestion (probably not the best one apperantly)

Answer (score 0):

The list seems to be bound to a view. So Clearing the list from another thread is an illegal cross thread call in this case. you have to set the right synchronization context or implement an async Version of the list. Here is an example for ObservableCollection

```
public class AsyncObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
  private readonly SynchronizationContext _synchronizationContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

  public AsyncObservableCollection()
  {
  }

  public AsyncObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> list) : base(list)
  {
  }

  protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current == _synchronizationContext)
    {
      // Execute the CollectionChanged event on the current thread
      RaiseCollectionChanged(e);
    }
    else
    {
      // Post the CollectionChanged event on the creator thread
      _synchronizationContext.Post(RaiseCollectionChanged, e);
    }
  }

  private void RaiseCollectionChanged(object param)
  {
    // We are in the creator thread, call the base implementation directly
    base.OnCollectionChanged((NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) param);
  }

  protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (SynchronizationContext.Current == _synchronizationContext)
    {
      // Execute the PropertyChanged event on the current thread
      RaisePropertyChanged(e);
    }
    else
    {
      // Post the PropertyChanged event on the creator thread
      _synchronizationContext.Post(RaisePropertyChanged, e);
    }
  }

  private void RaisePropertyChanged(object param)
  {
    // We are in the creator thread, call the base implementation directly
    base.OnPropertyChanged((PropertyChangedEventArgs) param);
  }
}
```